# Assign a Value to a Checkbox Field in Salesforce LWC When Updating a Record Using Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, checkbox

How can I be able to set a new checkbox field value to html or js in LWC upon update? I implemented a `lightning-record-edit-form` that acts as a custom edit page for a custom object.

I tried the following but the checkbox does not update upon submit:

**1st Attempt: via html using checked attribute**

`<lightning-input-field field-name="isDeleted__c" class="slds-hide" checked></lightning-input-field>`

**2nd Attempt: via html using value attribute**

`<lightning-input-field field-name="isDeleted__c" class="slds-hide" value=true></lightning-input-field>`

**3rd Attempt: via js controller**

**js file**

```
handleSuccess( event ) { 
   this.dispatchEvent(
      new ShowToastEvent({
         title: 'success',
         message: 'Success！',
         variant: 'success',
      }),
   );
}

handleSubmit() {    
     this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
     this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field.slds-hide').checked = true;       
}
```

**html file**

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
     <lightning-input-field field-name="isDeleted__c" class="slds-hide"></lightning-input-field>
<lightning-record-edit-form>
<lightning-button label="Update" onclick={handleSubmit} type="submit"></lightning-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're asking, so here are my two answers to each question I think you might be asking:

**If you're asking on how to update a field with `lightning-record-edit-form`:**

Check out this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_edit_record) for examples on using `lightning-record-edit-form`.

Your code will look like this:

*html*

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
     <lightning-input-field field-name="isDeleted__c"></lightning-input-field>
     <lightning-button label="Update" onclick={handleSubmit} type="submit"></lightning-button>
<lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Clicking the `lightning-button` will automatically update the record.

**If you're asking on how to change the value of the checkbox after the record has been updated:**

There are a few key things to keep in mind here on getting this to work:

First is what the `lightning-input-field` expects you to provide. If you look at the [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification), you'll see that it expects an attribute `value` which contains the field's value. In one of your examples, you tried using the attribute `checked`. The `lightning-input-field` won't know what to do with a `checked` attribute, as this is not an attribute listed in the specification. So use the attribute `value` for editing/updating whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Second problem: what type of data is `value` expecting? Unfortunately, salesforce doesn't have a clear cut example of how it represents a checkbox in javascript/html. I fetched some dummy data that contained a checkbox field, and after console.log()-ing the object, I could see that the `value` for a checkbox expects a plain old `true` or `false` boolean.

Lastly, I suggest you avoid using `this.template.querySelector()` to access/modify the checkbox's value. Since the`lightning-input-field` is a sub-component with `value` as a public property, it is better practice and more consistent with the LWC framework to assign a js variable in the HTML, e.g.

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="isDeleted__c" value={checkedFlag}></lightning-input-field>
```

And in your *.js* controller, you'll have

```
checkedFlag = true; //or false.

handleSuccess(event) { //the same handleSuccess() your edit-record-form uses
    //put whatever logic you want here to change the checkbox value
    
}
```

Furthermore, in your `handleSuccess()`, you'll have to manually update the record (probably with [updateRecord()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record)) if you want the checkbox value to be changed *after* the record has been successfully edited.

*Note:* In both of my solutions I removed the `slds-hide` class from all your tags, as that just makes the HTML invisible and wasn't relevant to the solutions.

Comment: My apologies if my question is quite not clear. As for the `slds-hide` class, I included it just for the sake of the checkbox field to be `true`. I implemented your suggestion to set a boolean variable in js and reference it as the checkbox field's `value` attribute in html. My previous implementation was I set the value to `true` directly in html, which did not work. The checkbox field is getting a true value upon update now, thanks for your help!

Comment: @lol No problem. I just realized what I said about the shadow dom was a little misleading, so I edited my answer. You can use querySelector and it will work, but it's better to do the js variable.